# jQuery UI Tabs with multiple triggering menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was trying to duplicate a jQuery Tab Menu to trigger the tab's content somewhere on the page (it might be placed in different divs also). I have also replaced the IDs to Classes but it doesn't work. Below is the sample code I made.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".tabs").tabs();
});
```

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3><strong>Duplicate(not working)</strong></h3>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the source code it is grabbing the first menu using `this.element.find( "ol, ul" ).eq( 0 )`. So  basically just the first ol/ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option api of tabs to activate the tabs programatically from click events on the duplicate.

Use `activate` callback of `tabs` to change the active classes on the duplicate links

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var $menu2Links = $("#menu-2 a");      

  var $tabs = $(".tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
      var tabIndex = $tabs.tabs("option", "active");
      $menu2Links
        .parent()
        .removeClass('ui-state-active')
        .eq(tabIndex)
        .addClass('ui-state-active')
    }
  });

  $menu2Links.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tabIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    $tabs.tabs("option", "active", tabIndex);
  })
    // show active class on page load on first duplicate link
    .first().parent().addClass('ui-state-active');
});
```

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h3><strong>Duplicate</strong></h3>
  <ul id="menu-2" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: PERFECT..! I couldn't ask for more! Thank you so much! :)